# Smoked pork shoulder

Tags: food-safety, smoking, pork-shoulder

We had a pork butt on the smoker during the night. When we went to bed around 11 the internal temperature was over 180. Somehow I slept through the alarm to wake up and check it. This morning at 6 when I woke up, the smoker was out of pellets and the internal temperature was 90. I have no idea if it was sitting in the smoker like that for 2 or 6 hours. Is it safe to eat of I heat up the smoker and get the internal temperature back to 205?